# Jquery access to servlet session attributes

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have an issue with displaying a div using servlet session attributes & JQuery. Please bear with me cause its hard to explain without context.

I have a "result.jsp" page. In the jsp I have a "Generate URL" link, an empty input text field and a "addThis" div. Link "Generate URL" calls a jquery ajax method "utilComp()" which calls a servlet that sets session attribute "saveLink", returns a value and populates the empty text field.

If attribute session "saveLink" is null (because generate URL not yet clicked) the div needs to be hidden when result.jsp is loaded. I do this by using if test="${not empty saveLink}" and the div becomes hidden.

My issue is bringing it back. I want the "addThis" div to display AFTER ajax utilComp() is done AND always once attribute saveLink is set. Anyone have an idea how I can accomplish this? Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

**This is the RESULT.JSP with only the important snippets displayed**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function utilComp()     {
        var jqXHR = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.central.com/sharemake.do",
            async: false,
            global: false,
            done: function(response){
        return response;
         },
         fail: function(e){
            alert('Error: ' + e);
         }
    }).responseText;    

    $('#savelink_id').val(  jqXHR    );
</script>

<a href="javascript:utilComp()"> Generate Link </a> 

<input type="text" name="savelink_name" id="savelink_id" value="<c:out value="${saveLink}" />" />

<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
   <a class="addthis_button_gmail" addthis:url="<c:out value="${saveLink}"/>" </a>
</div>
```

**This is the servlet code that is called by utilComp()**

```
String addressID = "http://www.central.com/generate"
session.setAttribute("saveLink", addressID);
String resultToReturntoAjax = addressID ;

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
response.setContentType("text/text;charset=utf-8");
response.setHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
out.println(resultToReturntoAjax);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a jQuery expert, but I think you can make the div visible by calling: `$('addthis_toolbox_addthis_default_style').show()`.  That should get all controls with a class of `addthis_toolbox_addthis_default_style` and make them visible.  (I'm assuming that your div is the only control with that class; if that's not true, you need to give it an ID and do a selector against the ID instead of the class.)

So you can set initial visibility for the div in your JSP based on whether the session variable is set at the time the JSP is run (when the page is loaded), and then when your Ajax function completes, use jQuery to set the div visible on the client side if it isn't already visible.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. During the initial jsp load, I now send the "saveLink" session attribute to a javascript function to check if its empty. If is not null, I hide() the "addthis" div. Then after the user clicks on the ajax function link, in a servlet I set the "saveLink" attribute with a value. Then I change the "addthis" div to show(). Next time the jsp loads, it will again check the attribute, and this time it will show() the "addThis" div. I didn't mention it, but obviously I'm also using the same logic to hide the "Generate URL" link.

So its doing exactly what I needed. Thanks.